# JasperReports: page's height

Tags: jasper-reports

I have some report that has a lot of non-recursive data that I want to put inside *Page Header/Detail* bands. But the problem that page has a max height which is 842 by default and it limits the band's heights. And if I try to increase that value so during the printing the page getting smaller because printer driver  tries to scale the page inside single piece of paper.

So the question is how it is possible to put non-recursive long data without increasing page's total height?

[image]

Template: http://en.textsave.org/g8L

Comment: write your code in header and set textField's property as `stretchWithoverfloew= true`.

Comment: @user1791574 The problem that I can't compile the template if I use the default height (842) - the footer becomes zero height and it doesnt't allow to increase the value

Comment: post your jrxml code.

Comment: with jrxml I cant understand, What you exactly want to get.

Comment: I need to put long non-recursive data into page header. this band's height is limited due to page's total height. if I increase it the output printed PDF looks terrible. if not - I can't be able to add fotter (in this case)

Comment: It looks like you want to put your text field in page footer but its height is 0.make sure that height of page footer adjust with all heights of textfield .

Comment: Yes, I know that)) But the problem that I can't, it says that page footer value can be no more then 0 because header filled all the height...

Comment: If you edit you question and post your jrxml code , then I can try to resolve your problem.

Comment: I saved it here - http://en.textsave.org/g8L

Comment: Why you using many blank texfield. Can you give any reason. If this is your main report, then you can use subreport to fill your data of detail band. And also it will much space for page footer.

Comment: Blank fields in order to add spaces after particular group of fields

Comment: You should use subreport for space. and also there is no need of blank text field, you just provide space it will leave blank space.

Comment: Regarding the empty space - I need it conditionally.. For example if I print out some group of fields base on some condition I need the empty space too based on the same condition. Regarding the subreports - thank you, I will try!

Comment: @user1791574 Post it as a answer, it really helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make subreport instead of pull all text field in main report. It will give space for content of page footer.
It will help you to resolve your problem.

Enjoy.